# Compare two data frames with same columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr, diff

I'm looking to compare two data frames in R and basically see where differences exist. Most of the answers I've found don't offer the solution in a format I'm looking for (e.g., found many answers comparing 1 column only, comparing only numeric value, showing only the total number of changes).

I've tried `waldo::compare(tbl_1,tbl_2)`, and that got me close, but the output isn't formatted in a manner to share with non-R users. The output format also isn't ideal for large data frames.

I've also tried using anti_join from dplyr, which got me the closest to the ideal output; however, the anti_join solution doesn't show which variables changed, it only lets me know if there was some sort of the change in any given row. My tables look like the below, but with significantly more columns and rows. Each table has the same columns and same number of rows. I'm ideally trying to get an output that matches the last table below (tbl_diff), but this is proving to be less straightforward than expected.

```
join1 <- anti_join(tbl_1, tbl_2)
join2 <- anti_join(tbl_2, tbl_1)
tbl_diff <- left_join(tbl_1, tbl_2)
```

tbl_1:

| id | state | widget | count | color |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| _bxhd7 | IL | widget_1 | 5 | green |
| _ex9un | MA | widget_1 | 2 | brown |
| _aolm0 | CA | widget_3 | 3 | yellow |
| _m017e | FL | widget_7 | 8 | orange |

tbl_2:

| id | state | widget | count | color |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| _bxhd7 | TX | widget_1 | 5 | green |
| _ex9un | MA | widget_1 | 20 | brown |
| _aolm0 | CA | widget_3 | 3 | yellow |
| _m017e | FL | widget_2 | 8 | blue |

tbl_diff (ideal output):

| id | state | widget | count | color |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| _bxhd7 | FALSE | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE |
| _ex9un | TRUE | TRUE | FALSE | TRUE |
| _aolm0 | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE |
| _m017e | TRUE | FALSE | TRUE | FALSE |

Comment: Perhaps you just need `out <- tbl_1; out[-1] <- tbl_1[-1] == tbl_2[-1]`

Comment: Yes, if the tables have the same rows and columns in the same order, akrun's solution should work. It says: create `out` as copy of `tbl_1`. Set all columns besides column1 to be a TRUE/FALSE based on if the values in those columns in the two tables match.

Comment: I think it is not difficult to solve (you just have to change the way you are focusing the problem), but please ALWAYS give a reproducible example. Use `dput` function in order to share the data frames you are showing.

Answer (score 1):

You only have to change the way you are focusing the solution. I will share an example using some random datasets (if you edit your question sharing your `tbl_1` and `tbl_2`, it would be better).

```
set.seed(666)

df1 <- mtcars[1:10, 1:4]
df1$name <- rownames(df1)
rownames(df1) <- NULL

df2 <- df1
df2$name <- sample(x = df2$name)
df2$mpg <- sample(x = df2$mpg)

require(dplyr)

bind_rows(df1, df2) %>% 
  
  group_by(name) %>% 
  
  summarise_all(function(x) length(unique(x)) == 1)
```